# Focal Loss Function For data balancing

Tags: python

[Code and error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RQ4Tv.png)

I am trying to balance the TON_IoT dataset using Focal Loss Function but I get this error

Comment: Please post the code in the question body not as a screenshot. Also post the error as text too.

Comment: [Doesn't seem like that module has `focal_loss`.](https://imbalanced-learn.org/stable/references/metrics.html). Why do you expect it to be available for import?